# How to properly Mask for a 1D CNN Time Series Embedding

Tags: pytorch, time-series

So I'm having an issue figuring out how I need to structure the data I'm feeding into my embedding layer. I currently have a tensor thats [sequences, features, timesteps]. I want to divide this data up for each feature into a separate CNN then concatenate at the end and feed it through an LSTM. I don't want the CNN to bleed future data into the embeddings for previous time steps. The only thing I can think of is creating a tensor like this for each embedding set [sequences, feature, number of timesteps, masked sequence] so each time point has a sequence that has masked all future time steps. This feels wrong but I don't know.

I tried doing this

```
# Create mask by setting future timesteps to 0 
seq_len = torch.LongTensor([len(x) for x in inputs])
mask = torch.arange(inputs_padded.size(1))[None, :].repeat(inputs_padded.size(0), 1) < seq_len[:, None]
mask = mask.to(inputs_padded.device)
```

But the resulting mask was 2d and was [sequences, timesteps] which didn't seem right to me.